# Link PHPMyAdmin MySQL databases to a PHP file

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm running into an issue while trying to link a MySQL database to a PHP file.
Im trying to setup [***this PHP login system from Github***](https://github.com/fethica/PHP-Login) and currently I'm trying to setup the [***dbconf.php***](https://github.com/fethica/PHP-Login/blob/master/login/dbconf.php) file. This is the code where I'm trying to link the database to.

```
    <?php
    //DATABASE CONNECTION VARIABLES
    $host = "localhost"; // Host name
    $username = "user"; // Mysql username
    $password = "password"; // Mysql password
    $db_name = "22445671_login"; // Database name
    //DO NOT CHANGE BELOW THIS LINE UNLESS YOU CHANGE THE NAMES OF 
    THE MEMBERS AND LOGINATTEMPTS TABLES
    $tbl_prefix = ""; //***PLANNED FEATURE, LEAVE VALUE BLANK FOR NOW*** 
    Prefix for all database tables
    $tbl_members = $tbl_prefix."members";
    $tbl_attempts = $tbl_prefix."loginAttempts";
```

The MySQL Database is named 22445671_login

***I am just looking for a way to link the MySQL database to my document***

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

**As put into my original question before it was removed. My website is hosted at at-space which comes with a PHPmyAdmin account linked to my website, I dont know how to link the MySQL database since I don't know if the username and password are just username and password. And I dont know if the host would be 1. My Website 2. atspace or 3. PHPMyAdmin**

Comment: You'll need to change `localhost` to the correct location of your MySQL database server. Further, have you created the necessary tables via PHPMyAdmin on the server?

Comment: Would the host name be your domain name? Or since I'm using the hosting service at-space it would be at-space? Also yes I have created the necessary tables. Also do you know if PHPMyAdmin default sets Username to Username and Password to Password

Answer (score 0):

1. Where is your database hosted?

You might need to replace "localhost" with the hostname of your server:

```
$host = "localhost"; // Host name
```

2. Make sure you have the correct username and password
3. Make sure the user has the necessary permissions

Comment: Would the host name be your domain name? Or since I'm using the hosting service at-space it would be at-space? Also do you know if PHPMyAdmin default sets Username to Username and Password to Password

Comment: The hostname might, in fact, be "localhost" if your database is on the same server as the file you are running the code from.

Comment: You have to create the user (via PHPMyAdmin) and grant the user necessary permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if PMA has this feature, but SIDU has this feature:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://example.com/sidu54/conn.php'
    .'?conn[host]='. $host
    .'&conn[user]='. $username
    .'&conn[pass]='. $password 
    // OR .'&conn[pass]='. $encryped_pass .'&conn[penc]=1' 
    .'&conn[dbs]='. $db_name 
    .'&conn[eng]=PDO_mysql' 
    .'&conn[char]=utf8'
    .'&cmd=Connect'
    .'&url=db.php'
    .'&id=1,'. $db_name;

echo '<a href="'. $url .'">Click here to manage database</a>';
```

Comment: I do not believe at space has SIDU.